# Tag adjustment: [sharepoint-enterprise] -> [enterprise]

Tags: discussion

The tag, `sharepoint-enterprise` is pretty long (especially if you often wish to add that particular tag), and I think that simply `enterprise` would do the trick; I think folks would readily understand what the tag means, and it would be intuitive to think to use it.

I suggest we either create a tag synonym for `sharepoint-enterprise` to be just `enterprise` or even just rename the tag.

Comment: Yeah... I'd like to get rid of any tag that starts with "sharepoint" but they keep popping up. IMO, version specific information should be included in the body of the question rather than the tags.

Comment: sharepoint-enterprise - meaning a tag for posts that only apply to the enterprise features - would be so abused that I would prefer we didn't have it at all, along with the version tags

Comment: The tag sharepoint-enterprise already exists, you know.  I am only suggesting we shorten it.